# SCRecorder:Record after coming from background

Tags: ios, video-capture

I am using [SCRecorder](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder) library for capturing vine like video. My problem is I am not able to restart a recording session when coming back from the background. If anybody have similar experience, please help.

I am using below code for restarting a session. It works well when coming back from another view but fails when application enter background and comes active.

```
if (_recorder.isCaptureSessionOpened)
{
    [_recorder startRunningSession:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Adding one more line to the above method solved my problem.

```
[_recorder pause];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) Intergrate updated SCRecorder

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [self handleRetakeButtonTapped:self];
}

-(void) handleRetakeButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    SCRecordSession *recordSession = _recorder.recordSession;
    if (recordSession != nil) {
        _recorder.recordSession = nil;
        if ([[SCRecordSessionManager sharedInstance] isSaved:recordSession]) {
            [recordSession endRecordSegment:nil];
        } else {
            [recordSession cancelSession:nil];
        }
    }

    [self prepareCamera];
    [self updateTimeRecordedLabel];
}
```